# How to print the json to listview included two data?

Tags: java, android

I want to display two data on listview through the json input. All the code are alter from internet which I got error. I have not clear logic to understand the meaning of the code. Please give me advice and alter my code.

```
  private void displayArrayList(String jsonStr){

        String[] from = {"eventName", "date"};
        int[] to = {R.id.eventName, R.id.date};

        SimpleAdapter  simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter (
                getActivity(),convertToＷordArrayList(jsonStr), R.layout.listview_layout,from,to);
        simpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
    }

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, ActivityInfo>> convertToＷordArrayList(String jsonStr){
        JSONObject jsonObject ;

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, ActivityInfo>> arrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, ActivityInfo>>();

        try{
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("article");

            for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject jsonObjRow=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                ActivityInfo activityInfo =new ActivityInfo();

                activityInfo.eventName = jsonObjRow.getString("eventName");
                activityInfo.date = jsonObjRow.getString("date");

                HashMap<String, String> map= new HashMap<String, ActivityInfo>();
                map.put("eventName", activityInfo.eventName );
                map.put("date", activityInfo.date);

                JSONArray jsonArray2=jsonObjRow.getJSONArray("content");
                for (int j=0;j<jsonArray2.length();j++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObjRow2 = jsonArray2.getJSONObject(j);
                    activityInfo.review = jsonObjRow2.getString("review");
                }
                arrayList.add(activityInfo);
            }
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return arrayList;
    }
```

ActivityInfo class (using the serializable to got the result )

```
public class ActivityInfo implements Serializable {

    String eventName;
    String date ;

    public void setEventName(String eventName){
        this.eventName =eventName ;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return this.eventName;
    }
}
```

Json Response is no problem

```
{  
   "article":[  
      {  
         "activityId":"5c5d8addd404c",
         "eventName":"running",
         "date":"2019-02-08",
         "content":[  
            {  
               "review":"you there"
            },
            {  
               "review":"please go away"
            },
         ]
      },
      {  
         "activityId":"5c5d8b318df62",
         "eventName":"basketball",
         "date":"2019-02-13",
         "content":[  
            {  
               "review":"confirm again"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "activityId":"5c5d8b9308018",
         "eventName":"playing",
         "date":"2019-02-16",
         "content":[  
            {  
               "review":"provid of you"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Post your JSON response also.

Comment: create a custom adapter with a custom listView item

Comment: What do you mean by two data? If you just copied some code from the internet and altered it, I think your best bet is to first fully understand the code yourself

Comment: two data meaning two text cover on two textview

Answer (score 0):

I totally do it like this:

```
public class menuCreation()
{
            public string Category { get; set; }
            public string ItemName { get; set; }
            public string Price { get; set; }
            public string FileName { get; set; }
            public menuCreation[] Arr { get; set; }


            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            string json = (reader.ReadToEnd());
            List<menuCreation> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<menuCreation>>(json);
            Arr = items.ToArray();

} 

            menuCreation mc = new menuCreation();
            foreach (var item in mc.Arr)
             {
                PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();

                pb.Tag = item.ItemName;
                pb.Name = item.Price;
             }
```

You can see, I reach itemName with class object.So, you can add listview with this method.

Comment: sorry, I don`t understand. Can you explain it?

Answer (score 0):

This is your Model Class..

ActivityInfo.java

```
public class ActivityInfo implements Serializable {

String eventName;
String date;

public void setEventName(String eventName){
    this.eventName = eventName ;
}

public String getEventName(){
    return this.eventName;
}

public void setDate(String date){
    this.date = date;
}
public String getDate(){
    return date;
}
}
```

This will be your final errorfree code..

```
private void displayArrayList(String jsonStr){

    String[] from = {"eventName", "date"};
    int[] to = {R.id.eventName, R.id.date};

    SimpleAdapter  simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter (
            getActivity(),convertToＷordArrayList(jsonStr), R.layout.listview_layout,from,to);
    simpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
}

private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> convertToＷordArrayList(String jsonStr){
    JSONObject jsonObject;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> arrayList = new ArrayList();

    try{
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
        JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("article");

        for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject jsonObjRow=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            HashMap<String,String> hashMap=new HashMap<>();//create a hashmap to store the data in key value pair
            hashMap.put("eventName",jsonObjRow.getString("eventName"));
            hashMap.put("date",jsonObjRow.getString("date"));


            JSONArray jsonArray2=jsonObjRow.getJSONArray("content");
            /*If you want to get Content Reviews from Json, you need to make another attributes like Content in ActivityInfo Class*/
            arrayList.add(hashmap);
        }
    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return arrayList;
 }
```

Comment: thank you! but I need to display two data on single listview such as ""eventName" and "date" ;

Comment: I edit this code, according to requirement of SimpleAdapter, So, try it, it will work.